# ASICMINER Blade Erupter Backplane Dimensions

Tags: mining-hardware, asicminer

I need to know the exact dimensions of Backplane ([http://www.amazon.com/ASICMiner-Block-Erupter-Blade-Backplane/dp/B00GPUDBSM](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00GPUDBSM)), both it's height, length and width. If you have one of these mining rigs fully loaded what I really need is the total dimensions of that entire setup.

Comment: Not the information he was looking for. would like the BACKPLANE dimensions, not the blade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dimensions are as follows:

Hasher size: 233mm x 116mm with a 227mm x 100mm x 19mm heat sink attached to its back

Power module size: 192mm x 89mm

Ethernet controller size: 86mm x 40mm

**Source:**

https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=204030.0